# NLTK edit hypernets/hyponets/synsets for specific words

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I'd like to add to the hypernets, hyponets, synsets of a handful of words for my text analytic project. (Or, set up a specific corpora associated with a handful of words for my project if that's simpler).

How do I do this? I've been looking through all the subfolders in the NLTK package file -- I know you can do this with StopWords, but can this be done for hyper/hypo/synsets?

Answer (score 0):

The `wordnet` synset seems like a corpus which is downloaded to these default locations on disk `C:\nltk_data (Windows)`, `/usr/local/share/nltk_data (Mac)`, or `/usr/share/nltk_data (Unix)`.

You can probably find the `wordnet` folder to edit the corresponding synsets.

Refer: [docs](http://www.nltk.org/data.html#interactive-installer)

Comment: But how does it know which word to assign it to? Also synsets maybe, but hypo and hyper notsomuch